# Double Tor functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I have the following topologically motivated question:

Let $R=k[v_1,\ldots,v_m]/I$ be a $k$-algebra for some field $k.$ And let $\widetilde{R}=R/J$ be the quotient algebra of $R$ generated by some linear ideal $J.$

I want to compute the following:
$$
\operatorname{Tor}_R(\operatorname{Tor}_{k[v_1,\ldots,v_m]}(R,k),\widetilde{R})
$$

I assume the result to be closely related to the initial ring $R,$ since for trivial $J=0$ it's just $R.$ Perhaps there is some sort of "double Tor duality" kinda like Koszul resolution is self-dual?

Comment: Are these Tor's $\mathrm{Tor}_1$? When $J=0$ you should get $0$ since then $\tilde{R}=R$ is $R$-flat. Is $I$ assumed to be contained in $(v_1, \dots, v_m)$? The result is $0$ otherwise, as this is annihilated by $I+J+(v_1, \dots v_m)$.

Comment: @PavelČoupek No, It's a tor-algebra, meaning I take all gradings

Comment: Still, $\mathrm{Tor}_{k[v_1, \dots v_m]}(R, k)$ is killed by $(v_1, \dots v_m)$ since $k$ is (I presume), so by the same argument so is the whole $\mathrm{Tor}_R(...)$, no? Am I missing something?